# How to apply a decorator to an imported descriptor?

Tags: python, numpy, decorator

I have a custom Timer decorator that I'm wrapping a bunch of functions with to time various aspects of my program. I would like to apply it to the transpose descriptor of [Numpy ndarrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html). I've tried this:

```
np.ndarray.T = Timer('computation')(np.ndarray.T)
```

but I get this result:

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Is there any way to do this or should I just replace .T with the transpose function in my code?

Comment: It's not a property, it's a descriptor.

Comment: Isn't a property a descriptor that looks like an attribute (i.e., array.T)?

Comment: Yes, the property implementation uses the descriptor protocol.  But not all descriptors are properties.

Comment: I'm sorry for the naive question, why is .T not a property? I can't find it in the numpy source.

Comment: Because it's not implemented with property.  If it were, then `isinstance(type(np.ndarray.T), property)` would return True.  There are other ways to do fancy things with attribute access besides property, read up about the descriptor protocol if you are interested in that.

Comment: Ah, so it's not a question of it doing something that properties can't, it's just not implemented that way. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it's implemented C-side, since its type is supposedly `builtins.getset_descriptor`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `forbiddenfruit` module if you really want to do this, but as the name suggests, you should avoid it.